# Entity Framework , how to only validate specify property

Tags: entity-framework, validation

I have a demo class "User" like the following:

```
public partial class User {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Required]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(120)]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Pwd { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
```

...
...
}

As you can see, "LoginName" and "Pwd" are "Required".

Some time , I only want to update user's "WebSite" , So I do like this:

```
    public void UpdateUser(User user , params string[] properties) {
        this.rep.DB.Users.Attach(user);
        this.rep.DB.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        var entry = this.rep.DB.Entry(user);
        foreach(var prop in properties) {
            var entProp = entry.Property(prop);
            //var vas = entProp.GetValidationErrors();
            entProp.IsModified = true;
        }
        this.rep.DB.SaveChanges();
        this.rep.DB.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    }
```

Parameter "user" like this:
new User(){
 ID = 1,
 WebSite = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
}

Notice , I don't specify "LoginName" and "Pwd"

This function can work fine , but I wouldn't  set ValidateOnSaveEnabled to false.

Is there any way only validate "WebSite" when ValidateOnSaveEnabled is true?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a solution.
First define PartialValidationManager:

```
public class PartialValidationManager {

    private IDictionary<DbEntityEntry , string[]> dics = new Dictionary<DbEntityEntry , string[]>();

    public void Register(DbEntityEntry entry , string[] properties) {
        if(dics.ContainsKey(entry)) {
            dics[entry] = properties;
        } else {
            dics.Add(entry , properties);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(DbEntityEntry entry) {
        dics.Remove(entry);
    }

    public bool IsResponsibleFor(DbEntityEntry entry) {
        return dics.ContainsKey(entry);
    }

    public void ValidateEntity(DbEntityValidationResult result) {
        var entry = result.Entry;
        foreach(var prop in dics[entry]){
            var errs = entry.Property(prop).GetValidationErrors();
            foreach(var err in errs) {
                result.ValidationErrors.Add(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2, Add this Manager to My DbContext:

```
public class XmjDB : DbContext {

    public Lazy<PartialValidationManager> PartialValidation = new Lazy<PartialValidationManager>();

    protected override System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry , IDictionary<object , object> items) {
        if(this.PartialValidation.Value.IsResponsibleFor(entityEntry)) {
            var result = new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry , new List<DbValidationError>());
            this.PartialValidation.Value.ValidateEntity(result);
            return result;
        } else
            return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry , items);
    }
```

...
...

Update Method :

```
    public void UpateSpecifyProperties(T t, params string[] properties) {
        this.DB.Set<T>().Attach(t);
        var entry = this.DB.Entry<T>(t);
        this.DB.PartialValidation.Value.Register(entry , properties);
        foreach(var prop in properties) {
            entry.Property(prop).IsModified = true;
        }
        this.DB.SaveChanges();
        this.DB.PartialValidation.Value.Remove(entry);
    }
```

Ok, it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[As I know](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cacc3156-6b5f-4412-a8b8-a1279d28a536) validation executed in `SaveChanges` always validates the whole entity. The trick to get selective validation for property is commented in your code but it is not part of the `SaveChanges` operation.